# SQL operation VS wp_update_term_count_now() related question

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I had some weird issues regarding the count of terms in my different taxonomies. That's why I expected to use wp_update_term_count_now() to solve it, but it seems the functions takes care only of specific taxonomies and not on shared taxonomies (where terms are used in several CPT).

Here's my actual code :

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    //echo '<pre>'.$taxonomy.'</pre>';
    $args = array(
        'fields' => 'ids'
    );
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
if( is_array( $terms ) ) wp_update_term_count_now( $terms, $taxonomy );
```

===> This function only update the counter of my main taxonomies, all the other shared taxonomies seems to be ignored, without any error.

That's why I have decided to do it with SQL directly, and it worked as expected if I update the count value globally, for each post type, like below :

```
 UPDATE alt_15846_term_taxonomy tt
     SET count =
     (SELECT count(p.ID) FROM  alt_15846_term_relationships tr
     LEFT JOIN alt_15846_posts p
     ON (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = 'jeux-video' AND p.post_status = 'publish')
     OR (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = 'logiciels' AND p.post_status = 'publish')
     OR (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = 'ext-navigateurs' AND p.post_status = 'publish')
     OR (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = 'plugins-cms' AND p.post_status = 'publish')
     OR (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = 'sites-web' AND p.post_status = 'publish')
     OR (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = 'services-en-ligne' AND p.post_status = 'publish')
     WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
 )
```

This SQL retrieves the count in every single registered post type all the terms of all the taxonomies of all my custom post types in order to show the PROPER COUNTER for each term.

My question is : how can I achieve this with wp_update_term_count_now( $terms, $taxonomy )? I see nothing wrong in my code, and no error so far...

Thanks for your help.